# Use insert id in a query?

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting into my pics table:

```
id | name
 1 | dog.gif
```

I also want to get the id of the above insert (1) and inset that in to another table (gallery table).

Is it possible to do this in one query or would I need two?

Comment: I think you need two. 2inserts - 2 queries. You can get the id of previously inserted row (if it is auto increment) by using mysql insert id, which will return last insert row.

Comment: see this: [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: I typically find it more convenient to have a `COUNTERS` table and not use _generated_ ids.  Its more portable, and can be faster (allocate the next 100 ids when you are going to insert more than one record).

Comment: @Lucas nice thought....worth adding in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO pic SET .... ;

INSERT INTO gallery SET pic_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is serial you can use `select max(id) from tableName`

But that's vulnerable to errors on simultaneous updates so use the method described below

From php.net [clickhere](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli::$connect_error() );
}
mysqli::select_db('mydb');

mysqli::query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysqli::$insert_id());
?>
```

But you need to connect for every query.